# how to find out details about the existing mobile plan (minutes and data) details of the user using an android app

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where in there is a requirement that I need to get the existing mobile plan details (for example, 500 minutes and 1 GB mobile data allocation per month) based on the users phone number/sim details.

I have tried using the TelephonyManager class, I could get the network operator name using the getNetworkOperatorName() method. But, got stuck on how to find the mobile plan details?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess thats not possible because it is decrypted

Comment: There's no general answer. Basically you have to find, if service provider gives any sort of api for that purpose and for each provider use it's workflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no on-device API for getting at plan details, in part because not all phones are on plans.

You are welcome to contact your mobile carrier and see if they have some Web service API that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for the response.